# Automator action to run python script on series of files fails in Catalina

Tags: macos, finder, automator, catalina, python

## Major edit

I've just discovered that the Automator workflow I'm having problems with works perfectly if I run it by pressing 'play' in the Automator window, and **it seemingly only fails when I save it as a Quick Action and try and run it by clicking the button in the Preview pane**.

## Original post

I have an Automator action that iterates through a list of files selected in the Finder, running a python script on each of them in turn. The workflow receives a list of files or folders in the Finder, and then consists of a single 'Run Shell Script' block with 'Pass input: as arguments'.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /path/to/python_distro /path/to/script.py "$f"
done
```

In Catalina, this fails with an error:
`The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “path/to/python_distro: can't open file '/path/to/script.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

How can I get Catalina to permit this? I've already tried adding Automator to the list of apps that are allowed Full Disk Access, and restarted Automator and `killall Finder`'d, but that did not fix my problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing a very similar issue too with Catalina, Automator, and python2. How complex are your python scripts? Can you run a simple `print("Hello World")` script from automator?

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces Yes, that works fine—it's just when I want to access files on the filesystem that it fails, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces I think I might have misinterpreted you—running `print()` statements setting the shell to Python works, but having `script.py` above simply be a single print statement does not.

Comment: OK - we're experiencing different problems then. Catalina also changed how PATH is set in Automator, so I am currently unable to import 3rd party packages into my automator python scripts

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces The reason that my `print()` statement works okay is due to the edit above. Although if you find out how to change the PATH in automator so that you can import third-party packages, I suspect that would also solve the issue I'm having here, so please post it as an answer!

Comment: You could try what I found here to see if it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717358/automator-cant-find-package-import-in-python-script-when-executed-from-zsh/58738617#58738617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case adding the Finder to the apps having full disk access in system prefs > security & confidentiality > confidentiality tab enabled me to run a Python script (without this I was also getting an "Operation not permitted" error).

Answer (score 2):

Running python scripts in shell scripts seems to work for me. Does the script have executable flags set?

Also, is there any reason you're using a shell script to pass the arguments to the python script, and not just embedding the python script in the Action?

You can set the 'Shell' drop-down value to `/usr/bin/python`, to use the bundled system python; or you can just use `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the start of your script.

Automator will even help you out by offering:

```
import sys

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    print f
```

to get your arguments into your script.

Comment: This way enables me to keep the script in a github repo and have it update when I make changes to the repo; but I’ll try both your suggestions and report back!

Comment: Marking the script as executable did not work, but using your `#!` trick to specify my preferred Python distro and then putting the script in Automator directly did. I won't mark this as the answer just yet, in case someone has an answer that answers the question more directly, but I'll do so tomorrow if nobody does. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm afraid I think I might need to unaccept your answer. Turns out the reason that the `#!` trick worked was because I wasn't relying on anything Python 3-specific in that script; but if I create an Automator workflow that just contains the 'Run Shell Script' action and have a script that's just `#!/usr/bin/env python` `print(2/3)` I get `0` returned, which is a clear indicator that Python 2 is running and not my Python 3 distribution. As such, I'm back to needing to run any Python 3 script from Bash, sadly.

Comment: (See also a major edit to the question to reflect a revelation I just had about the problem.)

Comment: @JohnCoxon Shouldn't it be `#!/usr/bin/env python3` ...? Without the 3, then 2 is expected.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python` loads Python 3 in my shell, but to satiate your curiosity, I tried doing a Python script in Automator that was `#!/usr/bin/env python3` `import astropy` and got a module import error; starting `/usr/bin/env python3` in Terminal and then typing `import astropy` was successful. More sleuthing reveals that others have reported that Automator ignores shebangs—see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463682/osx-automator-failing-to-run-python-script-with-modules-from-shell.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to repair corrupt PDF files from Finder as a Quick Action,

> without the need for an external Python file

In Automator I set up a *> File > New > QUICK ACTION* workflow:

Workflow receives current [files or folders] in [Finder.app]

Dragged a *Run Shell Script* action from the library with
Pass input: [as arguments]

Python code in a HEREdoc:

```
~/.pyenv/shims/python <<'EOF' - "$@"

import sys, os
import pikepdf # https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    pdf = pikepdf.Pdf.open(file)
    pdf.save(file + '.tmp')
    pdf.close()
    os.unlink(file)
    os.rename(file + '.tmp', file)

EOF
```

[image]