# Can't run python script from Automator on Catalina "Operation not permitted"

Tags: terminal, automator, python

I have a service in Automator that I pass a folder and it runs on every file in the folder. It uses a python script to read the album field from an mp3's id3 tags and write it to the Finder comment field:

[image]

This worked fine in Mojave, with each file's album being written to its comment. Now with Catalina when I run the service, every comment gets set to the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/thompcha/Documents/Scripts/album.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

- The script works fine if I run it manually from the terminal
- I granted Automator, Terminal, and Python full disk access in System Preferences
- I installed python via Homebrew as suggested in responses to similar questions
- I made the script chmod 777 and changed the owner to myself

The answer found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374284/83869) does not work for me because I need to pass the output of the python script to the rest of the shell script for further execution.

What can I do to make automator successfully execute my python script?

Comment: Please add the content of album.py (or share a link)!

Comment: You're not running your script with a Homebrew python, so anything Homebrew might have done to break things is not relevant.  Which python interpreter did you give permissions to?  The *system* python 2.7 is saying it can't open the script.  If you move the script out of your Documents folder, does it now work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in-lining my python script. The finished product looked like this:

```bsh
for f in "$1"/*.mp3;
do

    updated=$(python -c "import eyed3; import sys; eyed3.log.setLevel(\"ERROR\"); filename = '$f'; from eyed3 import mp3; f = mp3.Mp3AudioFile(filename); album = f.tag.album; f.tag.comments.set(album); f.tag.save(); print(album); exit(album);")

    comment=$(mdls -r -nullMarker "" -n kMDItemFinderComment "$f")

    printf "%s ( comment ): %s\n" "${1##*/}" "$comment"

    /usr/bin/osascript -e "set filepath to POSIX file \"$f\"" \
    -e "set the_File to filepath as alias" \
    -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"$updated\""

done
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve actual problem.

Comment: Actually, it does.  It does what the OP needed done.  It exposes another issue, though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not gonna write up a whole new question, but if you want to, feel free to link to it here.